# Keep lock after commit in loop with select for update

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, locking

How can i keep lock for table after commit in this situation?

```
for c in (
  select from tbl1 .. for update
) loop
  insert into tbl2 ..;
  count := count + 1;
  if count > 10000 then
    commit;
    count := 0;
  end if;
end loop;
```

Comment: You can't.  What is the problem that you're trying to solve here?  Your code would be faster if you did a single `insert ... select` rather than looping.  Depending on why you want to lock the rows, why you want an interim commit, and why you'd want to hold locks across that commit, potentially you could use `dbms_lock` to acquire a user-defined lock that could be held across a commit.

Comment: @JustinCave I need to process all rows in the table before someboby will change it and then enable trigger to handle new changes. I'm thinking of autonomous transaction but I think its not a good idea.

Comment: @mishok - that sounds like something you would do during scheduled downtime, with access blocked so no-one else can even attempt to modify the data (in any table) - not while your application is being used.

Comment: I'd second @AlexPoole's comment.  But if you really want to block people, what is the point of the interim commit?  That slows down your processing.  It might potentially make sense in cases where you want to ensure that you're not blocking another session too long but it doesn't sound like that's a problem for you.

Comment: @AlexPoole only one table in moment. i cant allow downtime of all service so i need to do it like there're temporary freezes.

Comment: @JustinCave i thought that it's too expensive to keep millions of uncommited rows in memory and it can be faster with periodical commit. isn't it?

Comment: Uncommitted rows aren't kept in memory.  Oracle is happy to write blocks with uncommitted data to disk.  Interim commits slow your process down (as does row-by-row processing).  The only reason you'd prefer to do row-by-row processing with interim commits to a single SQL statement would be if you expect your process to run for a long time and don't want to affect other sessions that also want to modify those rows.  That isn't completely unheard of but it does tend to be uncommon.

Comment: @JustinCave thanks for clarification. i'll remove commits.